# 2 external monitors with windows 10

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, windows-10

I have a retina early 2014 MacBook pro and 2 external monitors.

After upgrading to win 10 and upgrading NVidia drivers and bootcamp drivers everything seemed to be working fine. Then I plugged in my external monitors and notice that 1 was not working.

I don't know why, but first I decided to unplug the one that was working, and to my surprise the other one, went back on! So I plugged it back in, and the other just went black again!

I noticed that "the preferred one" is the one using the HDMI port.

I went to display settings, and besides both external monitors plugged-in, one 1 was recognized. THEN I went to Device Manager and **3** generic PnP monitors were recognized there! if I removed any monitor it "faded" out from there, and when plugging-in it pop-up again!

Now I don't know what to do! can anyone help?

Details:

- Everything is fully updated
- Video card is GeForce 750M
- External monitors are LG 22EA53
- All other devices (sound, bluethoot, thunderbolt-ethernet) work fine
- One monitor is connected via HDMI, the other via Thunderbolt
- Everything was working fine prior to win 10 installation (was using 8.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been having the same problem with windows 10 and many others seem to be as well.  I have AMD cards, but I believe using the NVidia control panel to set the screens may work better than the windows display settings.

Comment: that actually solved my issue! for some reason the display was "off" in the NVidia control panel!